# Beautifulsoup 4 prettify outputs XHTML, not HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse and prettify a bunch of files made with Microsoft FrontPage.
Beautifulsoup parses them with no problem, but when I try to print the output with `prettify()`,
tags like `<meta>` or `<br>` are rewritten as `<meta ... />` and `<br/>`.

Is there a way to force HTML output?

Comment: Any particular reason you dislike the XHTML-compliant syntax?

Comment: That output is still valid HTML, right?

Comment: _Beauty is in the eye of the beholder_.

Comment: I would like to use XHTML, but the person in charge is pretty ignorant and he'll be uncomfortable with this change.

Comment: That is valid HTML. Have you considered telling BeautifulSoup it's XML?

Comment: @ColonelPanic — `<meta />` isn't valid HTML 4 (except under weird circumstances). `<br/>`, in HTML 4, means `<br>&gt;` (although browsers don't support that syntax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to force the `.prettify()` method to not output XHTML-compliant HTML.

Comment: The output is not valid HTML 4. It is valid HTML 5, but that specification is still in draft form.

Comment: @Quentin: ah, my mistake, removed that claim.

Comment: My bad, I didn't specify that I needed HTML 4.